# Labeling Dataset for deep machine learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to create CNN Tensor-flow for text recognition, I already followed the tutorial on how to build it using the MNIST data-set, what I am trying to do is to add my own data-set into the model and train it, but the CNN was built as supervised, and my data-set isn't labeled. How should I give the data-set a labels, I tried to use different kind of labeling method such as labelbox and Amazon Mechanical Turk but didn't succeed. is there a way to label the data-set or convert the CNN into a unsupervised?

Example dataset:

[image: Here is an example for the data-set]

Answer (score 2):

There's several tools to label your dataset I personally used the following tool and it worked well for me it is written in python and it is very easy to use you can find the software and the instructions here: https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

If it doesn't work for you you can consider other tools:

- List item https://github.com/cvhciKIT/sloth
- List item https://github.com/Labelbox/Labelbox